# PostgreSQL internal server 500

Tags: postgresql, heroku, internal-server-error

Iam getting a 500 internal server error with this message,

> "message": "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "98.222.142.89", user "ykqkrdvlmsxktt", database "dp1g7eegdjct9ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidati", SSL off",
> "error": {
> "length": 216,
> "name": "error",
> "severity": "FATAL",
> "code": "28000",
> "file": "auth.c",
> "line": "520",
> "routine": "ClientAuthentication"
> }
> }

Comment: Wrong connection string. Share your connection settings (except for password) and you'll get help.

Comment: could you please check now